# Как в стандарте с++11 работает "наследование"конструкторов?

Tags: c++

Возник вопрос по-поводу использования ключевого слова using при "наследовании" конструкторов в с++11.

(Хочу уточнить, что я знаю, что согласно стандарту - конструкторы не наследуются, именно поэтому слово "наследование" - в кавычках)

Как работает ключевое слово using при "наследовании" конструкторов?

Что происходит в этот момент - конструктор из базового класса полностью копируется в объект производного класса или это что-то вроде делегирования между классами?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, вы зря так явно дистанциируетесь от слова "наследование". Стандартная терминология называет такие конструкторы именно "inherited", т.е. "унаследованными".

Во-вторых, работают они именно так, как описано в стандарте: если объект класса-наследника инициализируется при помощи такого унаследованного конструктора, то унаследованный конструктор используется для инициализации только соответствующего (своего родного) базового подобъекта, а инициализация остальных подобъектов всего объекта делается так же, как она была бы выполнена сгенерированным компилятором ("defaulted") конструктором по умолчанию.

При этом унаследованные конструкторы сохраняют свои права доступа из базового класса, независимо от того, где в классе-наследнике располагалась using-объявление. Доступа к `private` конструкторам базового класса вы получить не сможете, и превратить таким образом `protected` конструкторы в `public` не сможете тоже.

---

Так что можно сказать, что с точки зрения реализации, всякий раз, когда вы наследуете конструкторы из базового класса при помощи using-объявления, компилятору в классе-наследнике в общем случае придется на самом деле втихаря генерировать *новые* конструкторы с теми же наборами параметров: потому что кроме инициализации этого базового класса, классу-наследнику нужно также выполнять инициализацию по умолчанию для остальных своих подобъектов, а также, возможно, выполнять еще какую-то работу (правильно выставлять указатель на VMT и т.п.)